# Is there a way in SQL profiler to filter by 'TextData' filter with OR conditions for multiple text criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

[image: ap]I want to use TextData Like filter in the SQL Server profiler with multiple conditions to filter queries that contains any of the words. I have used OR conditions but it's not working. How can I use it?
Example - %Column1% OR %Column2%

Comment: You need to use `OR`

Comment: I have added OR condition but it's not filtering data

Comment: Please show your query (where you use `or`)

Comment: Image updated to question

Comment: So you have not used `OR`, but you put "OR" in a literal string. What you need is `WHERE [SOMETHING] LIKE '%somevalue%' or [SOMETHING] LIKE '%someOtherValue%'`

Comment: How can I determine [Something]? The criteria given is the column names.

Comment: Please show your actual query, not an image, but formatted text. Not just the filter, but the entire query.

Comment: Dear, I want to filter all the queries that contain any of these words.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you, I don't know, I haven't used traces in this way myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following illustration will help to solve your issue.
[image: Multiple Filtering]